# Как добавить ключ реестра на всех ПК внутри домена?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, active-directory

Подскажите, в теории, или примером кода, как можно с помощью `winforms` приложения на C# добавить ключ реестра на всех ПК внутри домена Active Directory

Или лучше смотреть в сторону клиент-серверного приложения?

Comment: Надо добавить в групповые политики. А уж эти политики распространят ключ на весь домен. Для этого они и существуют в домене.

Comment: Нашел только способ подключения к домену: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iRs71ovZ_U

Comment: Еще один способ: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFF0-tqdKUw

Comment: Машинами внутри домена, нужно управлять средствами домена, читай ActiveDirectory, а не изобретать неведому зверушку. Как бывший админ, руки бы оторвал, да и голову тоже, за подобное "решение на коленке". Ищи потом откуда ноги растут. Только через групповые политики. Точка. http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2016/01/19/nastrojka-klyuchej-reestra-s-pomoshhyu-gruppovyx-politik/

Comment: @rdorn: Может, напишете выжимку из статьи как ответ?